# Multidexing does not work when minifyEnabled is true gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

The app keeps throwing classnotfound exception after generating a signed apk. After much research, i discovered that it was only generating one dex file while the debug build has 3 dex files. After turning off minifyEnabled, it generated more than one dex file and the app worked well but now i have lost some obsfucation (ie the code is not well obsfucated)

Is there a way to enable multidex and still have obsfucation

Answer (score 0):

`minifyEnabled` is working for me with multidexing. Make sure you have set your obfuscation rules in `proguard-rules.pro` to this:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

Comment: I have tried it but it still does not work. It is still generating one dex file

Comment: Have you followed all instructions here? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: I have followed everything to the letter